# How do you list all symlinks in a directory that has non-hanging links?

Tags: linux, bash, symlink, symlink-traversal

I would like to get a list of all symlinks within a directory that has valid links. In other words, I would like all the broken links to be discarded in my list.

Comment: Preferably in bash or some other scripting language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In shell, `[ -L "$f" ] && [ -e "$f" ]` is true if and only if "$f" is the name of a symlink whose target exists.  So:

```
for f in *; do
    if [ -L "$f" ] && [ -e "$f" ]; then
        # do something with "$f"
    fi
done
```

(Never use the `-a` or `-o` options to `test`/`[`...`]`; they cannot be relied on to have sane precedence.)